# How to rename files containing a certain pattern in python

Tags: python

I have multiple csv files saved in different folders by month. They all contain the pattern `davo` or `DAVO`

```
"DAVO.csv"

"davo.csv"

"davo 2017.csv"

"DAVO 2016.csv"
```

How can I rename all of them as `DAVO.csv` in python?

Thanks in advance!!!

###### This is what I have tried:

```
for month in months:
    os.chdir(path + month)
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if 'davo' in filename or 'DAVO' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, 'DAVO.csv')
```

As in each folder it contains an original zip file with the same name of csv file, I got this error:

```
 FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when
 that file already exists: 'davo.zip' -> 'DAVO.csv'
```

Comment: Read the Error Message carefully: *It is not possible!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import os
import re
folders = list(os.walk(os.getcwd()))[-1] #list of immediate subfolders

files = []

for dir in folders:
    files.extend(i for i in os.listdir(dir) if i.endswith("csv"))

for file in files:
   data = re.findall("\w+", file)
   if data[0].lower() == "davo":
      os.rename(file, "DAVO.csv")
```

Comment: How is this an improvement over the OPs current code? It will still produce exactly the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out:)

the revised code is below:

```
for month in months:
    os.chdir(path + month)
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if ('davo' in filename or 'DAVO' in filename) and filename.endswith('csv'):
            os.rename(filename, 'DAVO.csv')
```